# How to disconnect client from socket server without server crshing?

Tags: python, sockets, python-3.7

I am making a server using Python 3.7. The objective of it is to have multiple people connect to it (currently one client for testing) and send data back and forth. The data being sent is a user's high score in my game. I want the server to get the data, compare the data to the highest score, and then send the data back and have the computer save it to a file. The thing is though, the client receives the text data as 0's and 1's! And when you exit the game and try to reconnect the server crashes with:

BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe

Here is the code for the server:

```
import socket
import sys
import time

servsock = socket.socket()
host = '192.168.158.155'
port = 5555
highest_score = '0'

servsock.bind((host, port))
print('Sucsessful bind')

servsock.listen(1)
conn, addr = servsock.accept()
print(addr, 'Has connected')


receiving = conn.recv(1024)
receiving = receiving.decode()

while True:
    if receiving > highest_score:
        highest_score = receiving
        message = highest_score
        message = message.encode()
        conn.send(message)
    else:
        highest_score = highest_score
        failed = highest_score
        failed  = failed.encode()
        conn.send(failed)
```

Here is the code for the game client:

```
# Read high score
with open('high_score/high_score.txt', 'r+') as f:
    score_contents = f.read().replace("\n", " ")
    f.close()

# Send data to server
lsock = socket.socket()

host = '192.168.158.155'
port = 5555

lsock.connect((host, port))
print('Connected')

ready_message = score_contents
ready_message = ready_message.encode()
lsock.send(ready_message)
print('sent')

new_high_score = lsock.recv(1024)
new_high_score = new_high_score.decode()
print(str(new_high_score))
with open('high_score/GLOBALhigh_score.txt', 'r+') as GLOBALf:
    GLOBALf.truncate()
    GLOBALscore_contents = GLOBALf.write(f'Highest Score:,{new_high_score}')
    GLOBALf.close()
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Look at your server code.  You accept a new connection, receive a message, then go into an infinite loop processing that one message over and over and over and over.  You never check for another message, and you never accept more connections.  Move everything starting with `accept` into the `while` loop.

Comment: You need to store your scores as integers.  Remember that as strings, "1" < "123".  That's not what you want.

Comment: _The thing is though, the client receives the text data as 0's and 1's!_  Of course it does.  All computer data is 0s and 1s.   As long as both sides agree on the protocol, as is the case here, it all works.  Your code worked once I moved those 4 lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The real root of your problem is that the `accept` was not in the loop, but here's how to use integers instead of strings.  Note that your `if` statement was always sending the actual high score, so there's no need to duplicate that code>

```
import socket
import sys
import time

servsock = socket.socket()
host = 'localhost'
port = 5555
highest_score = 0

servsock.bind((host, port))
print('Sucsessful bind')

servsock.listen(1)
while True:
    conn, addr = servsock.accept()
    print(addr, 'Has connected')

    receiving = int(conn.recv(1024))

    if receiving > highest_score:
        highest_score = receiving

    message = str(highest_score).encode()
    conn.send(message)
```

One other thing, when you're sending the score from the client, you convert the newline to space.  Don't do that; just send digits.  And you don't need "r+" permission if you're just going to read, and you don't need "r+" permission if you're just going to write.  Use "w" for that and skip the `truncate` call.

```
# Read high score
with open('high_score/high_score.txt', 'r') as f:
    score_contents = f.read().strip()
    f.close()
```